# How to click on a button inside a website?

Tags: c#

The HTML code is:

```html
<input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Convert file" title="Upload video to convert to MP4 format">
```

How would I go about clicking this button by using the `webBrowser` control?

I tried:

```cs
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit_button").InvokeMember("onclick"); // click convert video button
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were close, to click the link using InvokeMember, you just need to pass the string `click`.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit_button").InvokeMember("click");
```